Confusion with ALIGN 4, 3 behavior in ARM assembly
I'm currently reading "Embedded Systems with ARM Cortex-M Microcontrollers in Assembly Language and C" by Yifeng Zhu (Amazon link), and I'm stuck on a concept explained on page 88 regarding data alignment in ARM assembly.
The book shows following assembly code and the data layout:

DCB 0xFF        ; 0xFF is placed at address 0x2000 0000
ALIGN 4, 3      ; Align to a 4-byte boundary with a 3-byte offset
DCB 0x33        ; Where will 0x33 be placed?


What I am confused about is that after DCB 0xFF, the next address is 0x2000 0001, ALIGN 4, 3 should align to the next 4 byte boundry starting at 0x2000 0004, and with 3 offset, 0x33 should have been placed at address 0x2000 0007. Am I missing anything?

It only needed 2 bytes of padding to get to a location such that addr % 4 == 3.
The whole point of having an align directive take an offset is to avoid wasting space by going to a 4-byte alignment boundary and then offsetting by 3.  If you want that, do it manually with align 4 / dcb 0, 0, 0 (or whatever shorthand exists for specifying 3 bytes of zeros in ARMASM).
There's no other good way (in terms of other directives) to get what align 4, 3 gives you in the general case where you don't already know the alignment at the point you're using it, and it would be really nice if other assemblers supported something equivalent.  Most only let you align to addr % align == 0, or the GNU assembler lets you specify a limit on how much padding is allowed, e.g. .p2align 4, 7 to insert at most 7 bytes of padding to get to a 2^4 (16) boundary.  (GCC often uses something like that followed by .p2align 3 before tops of loops inside functions, so they're at least aligned by 8, maybe by 16 if it won't waste too much space.)

What if I have some data at 0x20000001 and 0x20000002, and then I do ALIGN 4, 2, follow by DCB 0x22,  will the next word boundry start at address 0x20000004, theeby, putting 0x22 at address 0x20000006?

Try it yourself.  But what should happen is that align 4,2 inserts no padding because the current position already satisfies the requested alignment of addr % 4 == 2.  Exactly like how align 4 will insert no padding if the current position is already a multiple of 4. If you want to go to the next word boundary first, do align 4,0 / align 4,2.

What software (free, like VScode) do you recommend for stepping through assembly code like this?

I use GDB on my desktop for debugging running programs, although if I had to do some heavy-duty debugging I'd probably look again for good GUI front-ends for it.  For just disassembly to see layout of machine code and data I use objdump -drwC or llvm-objdump
